# Knockoutjs with jquery autocomplete is showing symbols in the autocomplete results

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, knockout.js, symbols

I am using knockoutjs with jquery autocomplete which is working fine except the autocomplete results shows symbols along with the text.

[image: jQuery Autocomplete]

```
ko.bindingHandlers.ko_mission_autocomplete = {
    init: function (element, params) {
        var options = params().split(' ');
        var searchType = options[0];
        $(element).bind("focus", function () {
            $(element).change();
        });
        $(element).autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
            var keyword = request.term;
                //return result;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: SolrUrl,
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: '{ "searchSource":' + searchSource + ', "searchTarget": "' + searchTarget + '", "keyword": "' + keyword + '" }',
                    success: function (data) {

                        //alert("ajax request called successfully");
                        var tempData = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                        response($.map(tempData, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.Name,
                                value: item.Name,
                                id: item.ID
                            }
                        }));
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, errorType, exception) { //Triggered if an error communicating with server  
                        var errorMessage = exception || xhr.statusText; //If exception null, then default to xhr.statusText  
                        alert("There was an error : " + errorMessage);
                    },
                    complete: function (data) {                        
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 3,                  
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).change();
                $(element).data("valueID", ui.item.id);                              
            }
        });        
    },
    update: function (element, params) {
        $(element).change();       
    }
};
```

When i verify the json data it is coming correctly, however it shows as symbols.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: You sure the symbols aren't just a background defined in your CSS?

Comment: Thanks, I noticed the background image was being applied.

Answer (score 1):

are you using `twitter bootstrap` by any chance? This looks like there might be a CSS class clash.